# How to create new pages in wordpress admin panel

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a separate menu section on wordpress admin panel which will contain three pages. The pages will behave exactly like the normal wordpress pages, I just want to have a separate menu section in the admin panel. I am able to use wp_editor() to display the editor within a form. My problem is how do I get the content from the editor and how do save into the wp_post in the database? Here is the piece of code I have already come up with:

```
        <?php
            $content = '';
            wp_editor('test', 'mydescription', array('textarea_name' => 'my_description', 'tinymce' => true));
        ?>

        <p><div class="submit"><input type="submit" name="save_front_content_options" value="<?php _e('Save Changes', 'save_options') ?>"  style="font-weight:bold;" /></div></p>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for the Settings API:

- [Settings API tutorial.](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-2-sections-fields-and-settings/)
- [Settings API documentation.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)